# Android ROOM database testing uninstall within Androiid Studio - how to survive reinstall of app

Tags: android, android-room

I am developing an app that uses the ROOM database implemetation. The database is simple with only 2 tables.

I am trying to simulate what will happen with the persisted data when the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, hoping that it will be included in the default google app backup.

This is where I am confused - Within Android Studio I start a debugging session that re installs the App after Uninstall - I can add data to database running the app in a debug session or normally from the device. The database survives a restart etc of the phone and updated data remains.

BUT when I uninstall and reinstall using a debugging session I have a version of the  database come across somehow from android studio - one from earlier debugging - All of the changes since last reinstall are lost.

Where is this database copy coming from and more importantly how can I make sure that my db changes survive an app uninstall and reinstall.

I am using the path returned by getdatabasepath()

Any help or pointers appreciated on approaches to ensure this dataset survives app reinstall.

I am building the DB as follows

```
return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
       MyDb.class,
       Constants.DB_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
```

And getting an instance of the DB like so

```
MyDB = DigiDocketDB.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
```

Cheers,
Courtney.

Comment: Your app data is stored in DATA/your app name, Here only your app can access its own database, And when you uninstall your app all of your data is been deleted hence no data is stored. What you can do is ask the user to have a backup of the data, So that when reinstalling you can fill the data up again in the database

Comment: You can checkout this document. Maybe  help your solve your problem: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html?authuser=3

Comment: Thanks for this but yes i am aware of where the data is stored and I think that possibly the android automated backup may help, but more specifically I am curious as to where the copy is coming from, within android studio, that is copied back over the /data/application_name/database when the app is reinstalled from a debug session.